# Do I need to validate the cookie on every page load

Tags: php, validation, session, cookies

I'm using "remember me" function for my php based CMS and here is how I have set up my login system.

When a fresh user enters user name + password and gets validated by the server and then a cookie is sent to the client and a new page loads.

Now when the first page after the login is loaded I'm validating the cookie. I'm using "user_id" + "token" in the cookie and saving hash with salt in the DB.

What I want to know is, do I need to validate the cookie on every page load by making a DB query or using `php session` in the following way should be enough?

```
if (!session_id()) {
    validate_cookie();
} elseif ($_COOKIE['session'] == session_id()) {
    //get the previous verification result;
}
```

Here is a problem that I have to save the session_id() and last validate_cookie() result in client side. So is it practical and more important is it safe? or I have to validate it on every page load?

If you think I should follow any better way to do this then please mention it.

Comment: Another thing is that, is it reliable to store and use session data the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should!
But it is really simple :
make something like a `check.php` which contains the code for checking the session. And then `require()` or `include()` this code on your pages.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a "remember me" option need to work differently.

First, the "setting up" of the cookie is ok after the login with the checkbox.

But on ALL the other page, right after you check the session variable you need to check (if session doesn't exists) if his/her's got the cookie. With the cookie you remake a new session and use that.